# Are there more java mail servers like Apache James?

Tags: java, email

Open sourced or only free type license, simpler or more complex, but all written in java?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are.

- [JES](http://www.ericdaugherty.com/java/mailserver/)
- [CRSMail](http://crsemail.sourceforge.net/)
- [Java Mail Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmailsrv/)

Google is your friend.

Comment: I've alredy googled before ask a question and find what you mention, but I don't want miss anything so I wrote the question

Comment: @inquisitor, Generally, you will want to state what you have already found in your question. That way if people know of others they can answer. Good question though, I recently was looking for the same thing.